# Can't sendAction from event handler triggered by component

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I've got a component sending an action:

```
this.sendAction('action', data.files)
```

In the template I used the component like this

```
{{file-upload url="api/v1/upload" action="finishedUpload"}}
```

In the controller handling the event I'd like to send another action (to the same controller but I get the infamous `TypeError: undefined is not a function`

```
finishedUpload: function(files) {
  this.sendAction('insertImage')
}
```

How can I get the context of the current controller so I can send actions in the event-handler?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under `controller` you don't have to use `sendAction`, simply use `send` like this

```
finishedUpload: function(files) {
  //action to same controller
  this.send('insertImage')
}
```

When in the `component` you have to use `sendAction`